# position of "only"

Tags: grammar, adverbs, word-order, adverb-position, only

Which sentence is correct?

> - (A) *Mosquito larvae can **only** be seen through a microscope.*
> - (B) *Mosquito larvae can be **only** seen through a microscope.*
> - (C) *Mosquito larvae can be seen **only** through a microscope.*

Answer (score 13):

(A) *Mosquito larvae can **only** be seen through a microscope.*
(B) *Mosquito larvae can be **only** seen through a microscope.*
(C) *Mosquito larvae can be seen **only** through a microscope.*

As pointed out in [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/115157/15299), *only* focusses on another constituent in the sentence, which is usually stressed, and which controls where *only* can appear in the sentence.
The rule is that *only* may appear
either

- Immediately before its focus,

or

- Immediately before any constituent that **contains** its focus.
  (exactly like Russian dolls)

(B) is a little unusual, but not incorrect. (A) and (C) are both fine. They all mean the same thing, but each has different possibilities for focus, viz:

- (C) means that either *a microscope* or *through a microscope* is the focus of *only*.
- (B) means either the verb *seen* or the verb phrase *seen through a microscope*
  (a focus on *seen* is unusual, unless it is contrastively stressed to mean (e.g) 'not heard')
- (A) means that any of the above constituents can be focus.

Some people might not like (B) because the normal place for operators like negatives and *only* is after the first auxiliary verb, and (B) places *only* after the second one. However, auxiliaries are elided and contracted so often in English that the difference isn't really important or even perceptible, especially since *only* is much more complex than a simple negative like *not*.

Answer (score 1):

I'm willing, I guess, to be the foil to John Lawler and his sagacious answer and add a few not-so-sage sentences.

With the advanced photographic technology available to us today, we can see mosquito larvae quite nicely, thank you, in pictures.  Hence, option (C) requires slight modification.  E.g.,

> "Mosquito larvae can be seen only through a microscope or in a picture taken by a PAXcam digital camera via fluorescence microscopy used in cell biology studies."

Or, much more simply:

> Mosquito larvae can be seen only through a microscope or in a picture taken by a PAXcam digital camera."

As for options (A) and (B), each is likely to be heard today coming from folks who lack a certain, uh, preciseness in their speaking and writing.  Let me be quick to point out, however, imprecision does not necessarily equate with incorrectness.  If you understand what a person is saying, who cares if s/he says it in a less-than-precise way.  More often than not, drawing attention to a misplaced *only* will leave you only feeling embarrassed (or is that "leave you feeling only embarrassed"? or "only leave you feeling embarrassed"?).

Comment: Specificity has a use, and so does generalization. English has structures for both, unsurprisingly. Generalizing instead of specifying is inappropriate in some contexts, and vice versa. Neither says anything about mental characteristics of the people who do them.

Comment: @JohnLawler:  You had me until "Neither says anything . . .."  Sometimes inappropriate specificity or inappropriate generalizing can tell you a great deal about a person.  Granted, the person judging the inappropriateness could be dead wrong, but not necessarily.  That said, I'm a firm believer in the concept "Judge not lest ye be judged," which is very helpful indeed when I'm tempted to discern the motives of people without getting to know them first.  Abe Lincoln said, in effect, "Hmmm, I don't like that man.  Guess I'd better get to know him!"

Comment: That last sentence is best phrased as "More often than not, drawing attention to a misplaced *only* will **only** leave you feeling embarrassed."

Comment: @ Marthaª: Yeah, I like your version better! Thanks. Don

Comment: There's grammaticality. Then there's conformity to Gricean maxims. But then there's courser pragmatics: people often use intrinsically ambiguous statements, automatically relying on stress, commonest rather than strictly logical readings, and/or context to be enough to disambiguate. And then there are people trying to define 'correctness' as some complex function of these parameters.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Is the last sentence in your comment a shot, fired at me? Oh, and by the way, shouldn't "courser pragmatics" be "coarser pragmatics"?

Comment: (1) It _emphasises_ what you say in ' Let me be quick to point out, however, imprecision does not necessarily equate with incorrectness. ' Though I'd say few proficient Anglophones would choose anything but 'A' in conversation, even though 'C' is the precisionist choice. I just felt like identifying the components of 'acceptability' (and sidestepping the actual percentages involved). // (2) Of coarse it should. Apologies; a Freudian slip. Not even allowed to walk _to_ the local golf course.

Comment: Version (A) is a good answer to "Can mosquito larvae be heard through a microscope?"

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: The latest infernal commercial of Liberty Mutual Insurance Company on American television is worded as follows: "Liberty Mutual customizes your car insurance so you only pay for what you need." I suppose the argument could be made that the "you" in the slogan is YOU plural, but still . . .. How about, ". . . so all our customers only pay for what they need"? (In other words, all the other insurance companies' customers pay for more than what they need.)

Comment: Yes, different sentences and different contexts have different acceptability ratings. Some sentences need rephrasing, end of. Some need rephrasing in certain contexts. But as studies by Svartvik & Greenbaum showed, post-grad students of English Language do not agree on the 'acceptability' of various sentences, so 'acceptability' is ill-defined.