# "is only mentioned" or "is mentioned only"?

Tags: word-order

> The list was mentioned only at the meeting.

or

> The list was only mentioned at the meeting.

Comment: The list was mentioned **only** at the meeting.The list was **only** mentioned at the meeting. **Only** the list was mentioned at the meeting. The **only** list was mentioned at the meeting. ... All are grammatical; all make sense. They **do not** mean the same and one is **not preferable** over the other. For more, please visit ELL.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better asked on ELL.


Comment: And still it gets two upvoted answers. Beats me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [position of "only"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124351/position-of-only)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both would be understood, but in terms of style that "*the list was mentioned only at the meeting*" is preferable, and arguably clearer about what the 'only' refers to.

Consider

> The list was only mentioned (not sung, rapped, or chanted) at the meeting

against

> The list was mentioned only at the meeting (but not in the corridor, the lift, or anywhere else).

Comment: cool. It could have been only mentioned at the meeting but discussed during lunch. kudos

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to modifiers such as only, it's best to place them as close as possible to the word they are modifying to avoid confusion. Since you're stressing that there was solely one place/time in which the list was mentioned, it's modifying *meeting.* Therefore, it's better phrased as *The list was mentioned only at the meeting.*

With that said, both sentences are grammatically correct, and both would be accepted and understood. There's very little ambiguity in your examples.