# just/only usage

Tags: word-order, only

Isn't there a difference (or aren't there differences) with the following?

- I only drive to work on Fridays
- I drive only to work on Fridays
- I drive to work only on Fridays
- I drive to work on Fridays only

Though C and D may be the same.  Don't people usually mean C or D even if they say A?

I ask because in "Word Crimes", Weird Al says "You should only write in emoticons" but I think he should have said "You should write only in emoticons" or "you should write in emoticons only", right?

Comment: This looks perilously close to [the top question in the *Related* sidebar](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124351/position-of-only). What is here that is not answered there?

Comment: These limiting modifiers are notorious. D means 'The only day that I drive to work is Friday.' C would normally be taken to mean this, but could mean 'On Fridays, the only way I ever go to work is by driving.' B would normally be taken to mean 'The only time I drive is to get to work on Fridays.' A could mean 'The only way I get to work on Fridays is by driving' but is, as you imply, often used for 'The only day I drive to work is on a Friday.' In conversation, the difference is shown by stressing 'drive' or '[on] Fridays'.

Comment: If you place a subtle emphasis on the word drive, Option A could also mean, "I only drive to work on Fridays but I don't really work!"  For effect, let me finish with an emoticon :-)

Comment: Completely different.  He asks about mosquitoes while I ask about driving.

Answer (score 0):

> I only drive to work on Fridays

Other days, I take the bus to work.
Or, if the emphasis is *I only drive* / *to work on Fridays*: The only reason I'd be driving at all is to get to work which is only on Fridays.

> I drive only to work on Fridays

But other days, I drive to work, the store. On Fridays, I might walk to the store.

> I drive to work only on Fridays

Other days, I take the bus [to work].
Possibly, *I drive* / *to work only on Fridays*. There is a pun (drive: ambition) here. But even if *I [verb]* / *to work only on Fridays*, it still keeps that feel of *The reason I [verb] is to work only on Fridays.* (Yay! Working on Fridays only!)

> I drive to work on Fridays only

Other days, I might take other methods of transportation.

Note that most of the sentences can be read in different ways, depending on inflection.

In my opinion, the only true matches are A and D: (I only *something*) and (I *something* only). C matches, too, no doubt, but the whole sentence doesn't have an unambiguous tone.