# Difference between "I only have 10 dollar on me and "I have only 10 dollar on me"

Tags: errors

Is there any grammatical correctness in either of these expressions: "I only have 10 dollar on  and  "I have only 10 dollar on me" ?

Comment: Another: [position of “only”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124351/position-of-only).

Comment: You should use the plural "ten dollar**s**" in either case.

Comment: Very well Sumelic