# Placement of the word "only"

Tags: syntactic-analysis, word-order, only

Is the placement of the word "only" correct in the sentence below? If not, where should it be?

> Berlin is such a big city that we saw only a fraction of it.

Comment: _Only_ [can go immediately before its focus element (here _a fraction_), **or** immediately before any constituent containing the focus](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+only+mccawley+68). Here that means immediately before _a fraction_, and immediately before _saw only a fraction of it_, too, since that verb phrase contains the noun phrase focus.

Comment: You have one more option, to place 'only' at the end: "...saw a fraction of  it, only."  That use modifies 'fraction,' only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [position of "only'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124351/position-of-only) and [Correct position of "only"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5466/correct-position-of-only).

Answer (score 0):

Where it is, the word *only* refers to fraction.  If you moved it between *we* and *saw*, it would apply to *saw*:

> Berlin is such a big city that we **only saw** a fraction of it.

In general use, people would get the same meaning, but it isn't, in my opinion, pointing out the *fraction* as strongly.  That is, *only a fraction* says that you didn't get to see all of it better than *we only saw*.

But, both are correct and probably equal -- any differences in interpretation would likely be on the reader's part, not the writer's.