# "In only the city" or "Only in the city"

Tags: word-order

I am a foreign English student and have a question regarding the placement of *only* in a sentence.

I wrote *You can do all these things in only that city* in an exam, which is apparently wrong. But switching the order of *only* and *in* changes the meaning. I want to say that you can do all the things without leaving the city. Not that it's the only city offering all the things.

Is my sentence correct and if not, what would be the correct way?

Comment: Of interest: [position of “only”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124351/position-of-only). The word "only" normally restricts the term that immediately follows.

Comment: "You can do all these things in only _that_ city" is not ungrammatical, but sounds unnatural, and would only be used to emphasise a certain city when others have been discussed. The '_only_ normally restricts the term that immediately follows' advice is sadly not really helpful.  'You can do all these things only in that city' sounds more idiomatic (but specifies a location rather than a particular city), and 'You can only do all these things in _that city_'  (italics to show emphasis) would probably be the usual way of saying the same thing.

Comment: @Lawrence However, it can also be used in postposition.

Comment: @OliverMason True :) . But in the OP's example, I don't think that's the case.

Comment: @Lawrence Indeed!

Comment: This is a good first question. I just want to point you to another related exchange that might be of interest: [ell.se].

Comment: You write "I want to say that you can do all the things without leaving the city.". Do you mean that you can do all of those things inside the city, and also possibly outside? (This would be the normal meaning of that). Or do you mean that the city is the only place you can do them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is perfectly fine for the sense the Original Poster intended -  and Original Poster is also correct that if they move the word *only*, the meaning would be different. Unfortunately, however, the sentence is also ambiguous.

The two available meanings are:

1. You cannot do all these things outside that city.
2. You can do all these things within that one city alone.

The ambiguity arises because the word *only* can be seen to scope over the word *can*, which gives you reading number (1), or *can* can be seen to scope over the rest of the VP including the word *only*, which gives you reading number (2).

The Original Poster clearly intends meaning number (2), but there is no way to prevent the reader from understanding meaning number (1). Unfortunately for the Original Poster, if meaning number (1) is understood to be the intended meaning then this wouldn't be the most natural place to put the word *only* - which is why their teacher said it was wrong.

The best option here is a complete rephrasing:

> You can do all these things within that one city.

Answer (score -1):

*In that city* is a prepositional phrase, and *only* is not part of it unless you want to restrict your meaning to a particular city; so it cannot be placed inside of it. You have two options:

1. before: *do these things only in that city.*
2. after: *do these things in that city only.*

Both mean that that city is the only place where you can do these things. If you want to express that you do not need to leave the city, then you need to write something along the lines of *do these things without leaving the city*, or *within the city*.

*Only* will always exclude other locations, which is not what you mean here.

EDIT: I noticed a discrepancy between the heading and your example. If it is *that city*, then you could say *in only that city*, but again meaning that that is the only city. *In only the city* on the other hand won't work.

Comment: @Lawrence Sorry, yes, it's a prepositional phrase.

Comment: There is a difference between 'in only that city' (as opposed to in cities B, C and D) and 'only in that city' (as opposed to anywhere else).

Comment: Regarding your first sentence: "in *only* that city" is a legitimate phrase. There's no prohibition on putting "only" between "in" and "that city", except that putting it there might not properly convey the author's intent.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth & Lawrence:  Thanks for your comments. I have tried to clarify what I meant.